# Deployment files not updating (BitBucket, OneDrive)

Tags: azure, azure-bot-service

I'm developing a bot using the online editor, to add and remove files I was first using the OneDrive continuous integration then tried using BitBucket.

Using OneDrive adding files seemed to work but recently I wanted to also remove some files. I removed them from my local drive, waited for it to sync up to onedrive (I checked and they had gone from the web view) and then did a sync from the bot console.

The new files were created but the files I had deleted are still in the bot and screwing up the compilation.

More recently I have setup a BitBucket account and created everything there, connected it up etc and deployed to the bot account and it also doesn't change any of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. Maybe the files were in use and could not be deleted? Check `/LogFiles/kudu/traces`, look for `*_POST_deploy*`,

e.g. `2017-06-04T11-07-26_08882b_020_Background_POST_deploy_3s.xml`

```xml
<step title="Applying 2 changes ..." date="2017-06-04T11:07:27.231" >
    <step title="Deleted file D:\home\site\wwwroot\index2.htm"
     date="2017-06-04T11:07:27.263" />
```

Comment: There are no errors saying that is had a lock or a conflict. Each deployment appears to go through as expected but it never matches exactly what the source file store (onedrive or bitbucket) looks like. :(

Comment: There's something terribly wrong with your setup, at least git/bitbucket/github never had this issue and i've deployed thousand times.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the root cause is for why it was not behaving correctly but I have deleted & recreated my bot service account and the new one works fine.